# Loop Button inside the Loop Div

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm new here, I'm stuck in problem in which i have to loop my button so that i will be able to put it on my looping div. How will I do that? This is what I got so far:
 //my loop

```
for (i = 0; i < MPreply.recommendation.Length; i++) {
   html += "<div class='rec'> ";
   html += "</br> <div id = 'from1' value =  > Depart From:" + " ";
   html += emz + " " + "(" + + ")" + "</div>";
   html += "<div id = 'date1' > Schedule:" + " " + flytDate;
   html += " , " + convertedString;
   html += "</div>" + "<div id = 'to1' >To:" + " " + emz2 + " " + "(" + "" + ")";
   html += "</div> </br> </br> </br> ";
   html += "<div id = 'RecNo'>" + " " + (i + 1) + " )" + " </br> </br> </div> ";
   html += "<div id = 'fare1'> $" + em + "  </div> ";
   html += " </div>  <br/> <br/>";
   div_rec.InnerHtml = html;
}
```

html:

```
<div id = 'modal' runat="server" >
        <div id="dialog" runat="server">

        </div>
        <input id="_menuitem" type="button" value="Click" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?  Where is the code that generates the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least a few problems:

```
"<div id = 'fare1'>
```

and similar sections will generate multiple elements with the same id.

```
div_rec.InnerHtml = html;
```

Should be moved outside of your loop so that div_rec is only updated **once**, when everything is done.

```
emz + " " + "(" + + ")" + "</div>";
```

Should (probably) be changed to

```
emz + " " + "(" + your_variable_here + ")" + "</div>";
```

---

In order to (I think) add the creation of a button in your loop, you'll have to piece it together as a string just like your other elements.  To get a function handler wired up you'll have to either:

a) Build a dom level-0 handler as a string, or

b) Wait until your html is updated, then query out the newly added buttons and add event handlers in code (using either btn.onclick = function(...  or dom level-2 handlers (addEventListener or attachEvent)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem i see here is with the ID field.

You have mentioned same ID name for all the Div's you are generating.

Like,

```
<div id = 'from1'>
<div id = 'to1'>
```

ID is a unique identifier to an element. It must always be unique.

You can Use Class instead.

Like,

```
<div class = 'from1'>
<div class = 'to1'>
```